# how to iterate through intersection of nodes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, xelement

**How can I iterate only through the common nodes between two documents?**

Right now, I am able to iterate through all the nodes of my document:

```
var xmlBody = @"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Visit>
   <Person>...</Person>
   <Name>...</Name>
   <Color>...</Color>
</Visit>";
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlBody);
    foreach (XElement child in xdoc.Elements())
                {//do stuff}
```

I'd like to ONLY iterate through the common nodes between `xdoc.Elements()` and my `nodeList`:

```
var nodeList = new List<string> { "Name", "LastName", "Color" };
```

The intersection of the `nodeList` and the `xdoc` would be just these nodes: **Name, Color**:

**How can I iterate against the intersection, something like this**

```
foreach(XElement child in xdoc.Elements().Intersect(nodeList))
```

Comment: `xdoc.Elements().Where(e => nodeList.Contains(e.LocalName))` will filter based on the local name being in your list.

Comment: @juharr `xelement does not contain a definition for localname` https://photos.google.com/lr/photo/AHOXsYLU7wCrgaOisszJkRes3So0zXCDI3uItve4ojsFZk-XSYQz1k_9cBEJ1z19Ao7cBafY3PU7WiNg2MzU0lEvpYY8n6jBtA

Comment: @juharr Just keep in mind that this is a O(n²) solution, it won't work very well for big lists.

Comment: For a big list you should create a `HashSet` instead. And technically it's O(m*n) because the number of nodes isn't always equal to the number of names.

Comment: thank you, could you address the `xelement does not contain` issue?

Comment: It's actually `e.Name.LocalName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Linq Where and Contains like this:

```
        var xmlBody = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<Visit>
   <Person>...</Person>
   <Name>...</Name>
   <Color>...</Color>
</Visit>";
        var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlBody);
        var nodeList = new List<string> { "Name", "LastName", "Color" };

        var intersectedElements = xdoc.Elements()
            .First() //<Visit>
            .Elements()
            .Where(element => nodeList.Contains(element.Name.LocalName));

        foreach (XElement child in intersectedElements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{child.Name.LocalName}: {child.Value}");
        }
```

If you want elements that could be nested deeper than use Descendants.

```
        var intersectedNestedElements = xdoc.Descendants()
            .Where(element => nodeList.Contains(element.Name.LocalName));

        foreach (XElement child in intersectedNestedElements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{child.Name.LocalName}: {child.Value}");
        }
```

Both output:

```
Name: ...
Color: ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a list you probably should use a `HashSet` then you can use the following Linq to filter out the nodes based on the local name

```
var nodeNames = new HashSet<string> { "Name", "LastName", "Color" };

foreach(var child in xdoc.Elements().Where(e => nodeNames.Contains(e.Name.LocalName)))
{
    // Your code here.
}
```